# Adicionar plataforma ao projeto de Xamarin já criado

Tags: c#, xamarin

Comecei um projeto em Xamarin.forms a priori apenas para Android e UWP e fiz toda a programação no projeto Portable. Há alguma forma de eu inserir o projeto iOS de forma que as modificações do projeto Portable se integrem com ele?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim. Você vai adicionar o um novo projeto do tipo `iOS App` na sua solução, em seguida, instala nele o pacote [`Xamarin.Forms`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/3.0.0.550146) a partir do `NuGet` (adicione a versão correspondente à que você já está usando nos outros projetos).

O próximo passo seria você substituir o conteúdo do `override` do método `FinishedLaunching` na classe `AppDelegate` que é gerada automaticamente para que ele inicialize a página do `Xamarin.Forms`. O seu código vai ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    // Inicializa o mecanismo do Xamarin Forms
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
    // Começa a aplicação iOS nativa seguindo as especificações da classe App lá do seu projeto compartilhado
    LoadApplication(new App());

    return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

Se você estiver fazendo uso de outros pacotes ou plugins que necessitem de inicialização é nesse método que você o fará tambem, mas você certamente encontrará mais informações sobre como fazê-lo na documentação do pacote/plugin.

Espero ter ajudado.